# How can I save an image on Mac from a iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, uikit

I'm making a macOS app, starting from a IOSapp. In the iOS app, 
the screenshot is first created and then saved by this method:

```
void Bridge::SaveScreenshot(unsigned char * img, ssize_t size, int width, int height) {

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace  = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(img,
                                       width,
                                       height,
                                       8,
                                       width * 4,
                                       colorSpace,
                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

 CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
 UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
 CGImageRelease(imageRef);

 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rawImage, nil, nil, nil);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

The lines that gives me error are:

```
UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
...
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rawImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

I don't know how to change it to make it save the image on Mac.
Could someone tell me how to change them or what I have to use to save images on the machine from a macOS app?
Thks for reading and if you want answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MacOs image is saved as NSImage. So, you have convert UImage to NSData then NSData to NSImage and save the following way.

```
extension NSImage {
    func writeToFile(file: String, automatically: Bool, usingType type: NSBitmapImageFileType) -> Bool {
    let properties = [NSImageCompressionFactor: 1.0]
    guard
        let imageData = TIFFRepresentation,
        imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: imageData),
        fileData = imageRep.representationUsingType(type, properties: properties) else {
            return false
    }
    return fileData.writeToFile(file, atomically: atomically)
}
```

Usage:

```
   let yourFilePath = ...path to save
   yourImage.writeToFile(yourFilePath, automatically: true, usingType: .NSPNGFileType) // as png
   yourImage.writeToFile(yourFilePath, automatically: true, usingType: .NSJPEGFileType) // as jpg
```